# Como criar múltiplas tabelas de uma vez?

Tags: php, mysqli

Gostaria de saber como posso fazer esse código abaixo executar a criação de várias tabelas com [`mysqli_`](https://www.php.net/manual/pt_BR/book.mysqli.php) ao mesmo tempo pois no momento este código ao ser executado só cria uma única tabela preciso que ele crie no caso todas as tabelas abaixo em **negrito** ou até mais caso queira e permita também criar os valores `INSERT INTO` também de forma múltipla.

**Tabelas: medias_categoria, banners, medias, capas, seriados, configuracoes**

**Obs:** Caso seja necessário por essas tabelas para que minha pergunta seja melhor interpretada por favor deixe nos comentários que irei atualizar a pergunta.

E coloquei somente a primeira tabela uma vez que não está executando a criação de mais de uma por vez.

```
// Conectar ao banco de dadso MYSQLI
$connect = new mysqli($_POST['db_host'], $_POST['db_user'], $_POST['db_pw'], $_POST['db_name']);
// Checar Conexão
if ($connect->connect_error) {
    die("Erro na Conexão: " . $connect->connect_error);
} 

// sql criar tabelas
$sql = "CREATE TABLE `medias_categoria` (
  `id` int(255) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `medias_categoria_url` char(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `nome` char(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `modo` enum('UNICO','MULTIPLO') COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL DEFAULT 'UNICO',
  `data` date NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `categoriaUnica` (`animes_categoria_url`),
  UNIQUE KEY `nomeUnico` (`nome`),
  KEY `colunasIndexadas` (`id`,`animes_categoria_url`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci AUTO_INCREMENT=1 ;";

if ($connect->query($sql) === TRUE) {
    echo "Table MyGuests created successfully";
    
} else {
    echo "Error creating table: " . $conn->error;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Podes simplesmente usar a função [mysqli_multi_query](https://www.php.net/manual/pt_BR/mysqli.multi-query.php) que te permite executar várias *query* ao mesmo tempo.

Exemplo:

```
$sql = "CREATE TABLE `medias_categoria` (
  `id` int(255) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `medias_categoria_url` char(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `nome` char(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `modo` enum('UNICO','MULTIPLO') COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL DEFAULT 'UNICO',
  `data` date NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `categoriaUnica` (`animes_categoria_url`),
  UNIQUE KEY `nomeUnico` (`nome`),
  KEY `colunasIndexadas` (`id`,`animes_categoria_url`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci AUTO_INCREMENT=1 ; "

$sql .= "CREATE TABLE `banners` ... ; ";
// depois as restantes

$connect->multi_query( $sql );

// ou mysqli_multi_query ( $connect , $sql );
```

Embora eu recomende que cries uma tabela de cada vez.

```
$connect->query( $sql_medias_categoria );
$connect->query( $sql_banners          );
// depois as restantes
```

**Nota: Não esquecer a dependência entre tabelas senão pode dar asneira.**

Comment: Grato pela ajuda.